# Interpolation with MATLAB in EMG processing

Tags: matlab, post-processing, spatial-interpolation

I have 3 `EMG` recordings for 2 muscles, with a sampling rate of 1000Hz. In other words I have 3 matrices of `EMG` data; each has 2 rows (for 2 muscles).

However the number of samples (columns) in each isn't the same: the first one has 2600 samples, the second has 2500 samples and the third one has 2550 samples.

I want to make their lengths the same as each other, to get 3 matrices with the same number of rows and columns. I think it is foolish to cut the bigger ones and use just 2500 columns. However if I want to do so, I don't know whether I should cut from the start or end of them?

Is there a way in MATLAB to interpolate the data to get 3 matrices, each of size 3 x 2600?

All 3 matrices belong to the same movement, and I want to match the samples.

Comment: Do you have any starting code?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to look at using interp1 in this situation.  This performs an interpolation between your points so that you can sample at any position on the x-axis.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html

I have the following example which has some random sample data `sample1`, `sample2` and `sample3`.  These variables are of lengths 2600, 2500 and 2550 respectively.

```
sample1 = exp(2*linspace(0,1,2600)+rand(1, 2600));
sample2 = exp(linspace(0,1,2500)+rand(1, 2500));
sample3 = exp(3*linspace(0,1,2550)+rand(1, 2550));
```

I have a desired length (I am using a length which corresponds to your *shortest* sample size)

```
desiredlength = 2500;
```

You can then interpolate your data with the following code (note the default is a linear interpolation):

```
adjusted = zeros(3, desiredlength);

adjusted(1, :) = interp1(linspace(0,1,length(sample1)), sample1, linspace(0,1,desiredlength));
adjusted(2, :) = interp1(linspace(0,1,length(sample2)), sample2, linspace(0,1,desiredlength));
adjusted(3, :) = interp1(linspace(0,1,length(sample3)), sample3, linspace(0,1,desiredlength));

plot(adjusted')
```

[image]

`linspace(a, b, n)` is a function which gives you a vector of `n` points between `a` and `b`, and for `sample1` I am transforming from `linspace(0, 1, 2600)` to `linspace(0, 1, 2500)`

I hope this helps.